# how do I reduce the size of the box, I tried changing the width and height of it in media query but they weren't being applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, css-grid

[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vgnt.jpg)  [smaller width view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmrjR.png)  [code of the boxes in desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNyqF.png)
`- I am new to this and just started building this website but got stuck here.
- I changed the grid-template-columns, width and height to fit the size in the media query but they                    -weren't word.
-
- I tried:

```
@media (max-width:700px){
    
    .content-one1, .content-one2, .content-one3{
        width: 10px;
        height: 20px;
    }
}
```

```
- but it wasn't working  `
```

Comment: It isn't working because the original code is superseding it, you can try `@media only screen (max-width: 700px) {your css here}`

Comment: First, set your style for all views `.item {...}` . Below that, set your style for `@media (max-width: 700px) { .item {...} }`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use (orientation:portrait) and give a width and height like this**.

```
@media (min-width: 40.7rem), (orientation: portrait) {
 .content-one1, .content-one2, .content-one3{
        width: 40%;
        height: 40%;
    } }
```

> use percentages instead of pixels. Pixels not scalable its definite.
> use rem instead of pixels like margin, padding for those properties
> 1rem = 16px